# How to uniquely identify UIImage picked from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsfilemanager

I have picked an image from photo library using `UIImagePickerController`. Now I want to save that image in documents folder. I have also got the url of that folder.

Problem is what name should I assign to image so that I can uniquely identify it? If I add date time stamp with image name, then user can save two same images from photos library with different names in documents folder which is undesirable.

Or is there some logic to compare two `UIImage`s to check if it already exists?

Comment: I think you should give a clearer description for your question. The user can pick images from album many times, but you just want to save the last image?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a hash of the file url - you can see this implemented in https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.m

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two images, if they are the same or not you can try this.

```
if([UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2)])
{
 NSLog(@"Same images");
}
```

Comment: He is asking about filenames, not comparing if two images are the same image.

Comment: Comparing can also be helpful to check if the selected image already exists in my folder but it is an expensive process and takes a lot of time coz I have so many images to compare with before saving :(